# How to alert user upon update of chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a chrome app that I am going to be updating and the update will break previous saves. Now I would like to alert the users of the app upon successful completion of the update. I do have an chrome api that I am trying to use which is:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){

});
```

Now I have read the `chrome.runtime` developer docs and it says that I can use:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function callback)
```

With a callback function of:

```
function(object details) {...};
```

The problem is that I can not figure out what exactly to do with the info as I have tried a couple of different set ups with this code but none work. any help with this issue would be appreciated

Please note that I am trying to display a window that would contain this message. Also my current code is in the background.js of my app although as said the code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) mentions one property of `details`:

> `reason`
>
> enum of `"install"`, `"update"`, `"chrome_update"`, or `"shared_module_update"`
>
> The reason that this event is being dispatched.

So your code needs to check that:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
  if(details.reason == "update") {
    // Inform the user of the sad news
  }
});
```

Comment: As an additional bonus, you can check your extension's version in the code with [`chrome.runtime.getManifest()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest)

Comment: Nice tip I will remember it as it may just come in handy.

Comment: You can also be a little more proactive with this in the case where your app is already running when an update comes: listen to `onUpdateAvailable` (its callback also has `details` parameter with the `version` field indicating the available update). Then you can force updating using `chrome.runtime.reload()`.